# Regular expression for hosts file behaves differently

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to parse my host file from a PowerShell script.

I observe different behavior:

1. Setup :

   ```
   $hostsFile = "$env:windir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
   $hostsRegex = '^\s*(?<Address>[0-9\.\:]+)\s+(?<Host>[\w\.\-]+)\s*$'

   $entries = Get-Content $hostsFile -Encoding Ascii
   ```
2. using `-match`:

   ```
   $entries -match $hostsRegex
   ```

   It behaves as expected, and outputs all my entries (and only my entries).
3. using .Net `Regex.Matches` method:

   ```
   [Regex]::Matches($entries, $hostsRegex)
   ```

   Nothing is returned (also tried using options like `Multiline`,`SingleLine`, etc...

My goal is to get a custom PS object, for further processing. Actually I want this to works :

```
function Get-HostsEntries{
    $hostsFile = "$env:windir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
    $hostsRegex = '^\s*(?<Address>[0-9\.\:]+)\s+(?<Host>[\w\.\-]+)\s*$'

    $entries = Get-Content $hostsFile -Encoding Ascii

    [Regex]::Matches($entries, $hostsRegex ) | %{
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Address = $_.Groups["Address"].Value
            Host = $_.Groups["Host"].Value
        }
    }
}

Get-HostsEntries
```

But nothing is returned.

So my questions are :

1. Why does the PowerShell and .Net call do not behave in the same way?
2. How to fix my script to works as expected?

Comment: `$entries` is a collection of strings, `Regex.Matches()` take *a single* string as its first argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-Raw` to read the file into a single string. Otherwise `Get-Content` gives you a list of strings, which `[Regex]::Matches` doesn't handle.

```
$hostsFile = "$env:windir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
$entries = Get-Content $hostsFile -Encoding Ascii -Raw

$hostsRegex = [Regex]'(?m)^\s*(?<Address>[0-9.:]+)\s+(?<Host>[\w.-]+)'
$hostsRegex.Matches($entries)
```

works fine for me.

Note the `(?m)` multiline modifier in the regex. Also, it's not necessary to escape `.`, `:` or `-` inside character classes.

Lastly am casting the expression to `[Regex]` straight-away, thereby removing the need to jump through "static method" hoops later-on.

Comment: Using `-raw` solved my problem (also specified `Multiline` parameter in the method call). Thanks !